# GStreamer appsink is much more slower than filesink

Tags: go, gstreamer

I'm trying to convert an MP3 file to wave using GStreamer in golang. Here is the `createPipeline()` function:

```
func createPipeline() (*gst.Pipeline, error) {
    gst.Init(nil)

    // Create a pipeline
    pipeline, err := gst.NewPipelineFromString(
        "appsrc name=src ! decodebin ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,format=S16LE,rate=16000 ! wavenc ! appsink name=sink")

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    srcElem, err := pipeline.GetElementByName("src")

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    src := app.SrcFromElement(srcElem)
    src.SetCallbacks(&app.SourceCallbacks{
        NeedDataFunc: func(self *app.Source, _ uint) {

            // If we've reached the end of the palette, end the stream.
            bytes, _ := os.ReadFile("/tmp/a.mp3")
            buffer := gst.NewBufferFromBytes(bytes)
            self.PushBuffer(buffer)
            src.EndStream()
        },
    })

    sinkElem, err := pipeline.GetElementByName("sink")

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    sink := app.SinkFromElement(sinkElem)
    sink.SetCallbacks(&app.SinkCallbacks{
        // Add a "new-sample" callback
        NewSampleFunc: func(sink *app.Sink) gst.FlowReturn {

            // Pull the sample that triggered this callback
            sample := sink.PullSample()
            if sample == nil {
                return gst.FlowEOS
            }

            os.WriteFile("a.wav", sample.GetBuffer().Bytes(), 0644)

            return gst.FlowOK
        },
    })

    return pipeline, nil
}
```

I had two choices. The first one was using a `filesink` element to save the result to a file and the second one was to use a `appsink` element and to get the samples and write to file. I thought the performance should be almost the same for these two approaches. But when I used `appsink` it took much more langer than `filesink`. I'm using [this binding](https://github.com/tinyzimmer/go-gst/) of GStreamer for go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `appsink` syncs to the clock by default while `filesink` does not. So when you use `appsink` the buffers will be synchronized to the pipeline clock - this will make your pipeline run in real-time (and not faster). Set the `sync` property of your appsink to `false`: `.. ! appsink name=sink sync=false`.

Comment: No effect. it took 3.94 seconds. But the other approach took 126.086975ms

Comment: Maybe it is the additional memory copy from C space to Go? On the other hand you are using Writefile which creates writes and cloeses a file on each received sample.

Comment: yep. you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You can try latency tracer for checking the latency between elements of the pipeline. If it is the same for both pipelines, it is probably due to disk io and can be solved by buffering before writing to disk.